# Why can't you see the curvature of the Earth on the horizon?

Tags: earth

Because you're on a sphere. No matter which way you look, the horizon is the same distance from you creating a flat plane around you. Even on a high mountain you'll never see the curve on the horizon.

At every degree you turn, the curvature is between you and the horizon. Draw a circle on a Walmart rubber ball. The circle is the horizon and you are always the center of that circle no matter where you are on a sphere. Notice the circle on the ball curves around you creating a flat plain.

Still don't get it? Take an orange and draw a circle on it. Now slice off the orange at the circle. Notice the horizon (edge of the circle) is flat? Flat earther's own questions debunk their claim. This is kindergarten stuff

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This doesn't really fit the stackexchange format.  This should be a question, but you seem to have a loosely worded answer here.

Comment: He has posted a question in the title, and answered it himself.

Comment: @mmesser314 That is what I'm saying.  This is supposed to be a question.  Answers would go below in the answer area.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your argument is wrong:
People can see curvature of earth.

On shore, sailing ships appear (or disappear) top sail first (or last).

Going higher let's you see farther.

In addition, if you're near space or in space, you can see the curvature perpendicular to you.